# Swift 3 - addChildViewController on UIWindow of another view controller

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwindow, childviewcontroller, childviews

I have to add second view controller's view on UIWindow of the first view controller using `addChildViewController`. but I'm getting issue when I'm trying to do that. My query is, it is possible to add that another view controller's view on UIWindow?

```
    secondVC = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC"))!
    self.addChildViewController(secondVC)
    self.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    draw.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, 320, 568)

    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    window?.addSubview(secondVC.view)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you should instantiate the root VC and then add the second VC into the first VC of your app. For example you could write something like that:

```
//init the storyboard
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
//init the firstVC
let navigation = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
let firstVC = navigation.viewControllers[0]
//init the second VC
let secondVC = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC"))!
//add child VC
firstVC.addChildViewController(secondVC)
secondVC.view.frame = firstVC.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
secondVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

This is because the main window has the root VC associated. The keywindow has the initial view controller from the main Storyboard.

Comment: Well, Do u mean that you embed a navigation controller on your root vc?

Comment: Yeah. I linked the navigation controller to first viewcontroller

Comment: Ok, In that case you need to put a storyboard ID on your navigation controller and then instantiate your firstVC as a navigation vc, then you can get the viewControllers's property of navigation controller and get the firstView controller to add your child VC. I will edit the code.